Swagger UI from Springdoc 1.8 not working with multi-module Maven project
We have a Maven project with Spring Boot 2.7.
We have several maven modules in the maven project, including two with MVC REST APIs, and one common.
The two REST API modules build separate services which are run on different servers with using java -cp module.
We added this to one of the REST API modules:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

and as if by magic, we see the Swagger UI on http://localhost:8091/swagger-ui/index.html
We then added the same dependency to the pom file of the other service, but hitting the corresponding URL gives 404.
There is nothing in the logs. How do we debug this?
The second service is pretty much the same as the first, both have a single @RestController defined with a @RestMapping, and a WebConfiguration class which implements WebMvcConfigurer etc.
The web configuration is the same for both modules.
Any suggestions how to debug?
Interestingly, if I add the springdoc-openapi-ui dependency to the common module, and remove it from the two REST modules, it works but only shows the REST APIs of the one module it worked for before.

I had problems with the very similar issue -
just instead of using springdoc-openapi-ui I am using springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.
The problem I had was, that while in the single module, my RestController is implementing DocumentsApiDelegate, but in multi module I had to implement DocumentsApi (not "Delegate").

More details about springdoc-openapi-v1 & springdoc-openapi-v2:
https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springdoc-v1

I found a workaround.  In both modules, I added the OpenAPIDefinition annotation and it started working.  This requires adding an additional dependency to the pom file unfortunately
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info;

@SpringBootApplication
@OpenAPIDefinition(info =
@Info(title = "My api", version = "1.0", description = "My api v1.0")
)
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

}

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.20</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

